# Align 3 elements in a row and another one on the side

Tags: html, css

I have 4 elements that need to be relative aligned:

- The first three would need to be stacked on top of each other in a column
- The fourth (blue box) should be aligned on the right side of the column.

The HTML code is as follows, and can't be altered:

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="smallblock1"></div>
  <div class="smallblock2"></div>
  <div class="smallblock3"></div>
  <div class="Largeblock"></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to achieve the desired alignment with CSS, without using absolute positioning?

```css
#container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.smallblock1 {
  width: 200px; 
  height:200px;
  background-color:black; 
}
.smallblock2 {
  width: 200px; 
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;  
}
.smallblock3 {
  width: 200px; 
  height:200px;
  background-color:yellow;      
}
.Largeblock {
  width:500px; 
  height:1000px;
  background-color:blue;   
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="smallblock1"></div>
  <div class="smallblock2"></div>
  <div class="smallblock3"></div>
  <div class="Largeblock"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we re-structre the HTML?

Comment: No not possible unfortunaly.

Comment: 3 in a row or in a column?

Comment: Stacking things vertically would create a column, not a row.

Answer (score 0):

You can [float](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats) and [clear](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#flow-control) the small blocks.

```css
.smallblock1, .smallblock2, .smallblock3 {
  float: left; /* Push them to the left */
  clear: left; /* Stack them on top of each other */
}
```

Usually, elements that follow floats overlap their margin box. This can be avoided by forcing the element to establish a [block formatting context (BFC)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting), e.g. using `overflow: hidden` on it.

```css
.Largeblock { overflow: hidden; } /* Establish a block formatting context */
```

And then, to align the big one to the right, you can use [`direction`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-direction).

```css
#container { direction: rtl; }     /* Align the big block to the right */
#container > * { direction: ltr; } /* Restore the default value */
```

```css
#container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: grey;
  direction: rtl;
}
#container > * {
  direction: ltr;
}
.smallblock1,
.smallblock2,
.smallblock3 {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
.smallblock1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}
.smallblock2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.smallblock3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.Largeblock {
  width: 500px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id ="container">
  <div class="smallblock1"></div>
  <div class="smallblock2"></div>
  <div class="smallblock3"></div>
  <div class="Largeblock"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively (but still floating and clearing the small blocks), you can [display](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#display-prop) the big block as an `inline-block`.

```css
.Largeblock { display: inline-block; } /* Align it according to text-align
                                          and make it establish a BFC */
```

This way it will become an [inline-level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-level), so you will be able to align it using [`text-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#alignment-prop).

```css
#container { text-align: right; }    /* Align the big block to the right */
#container > * { text-align: left; } /* Restore the default value */
```

Additionally, since `inline-block`s establish block formatting contexts, there is no need of `overflow: hidden`.

```css
#container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: right;
}
#container > * {
  text-align: left;
}
.smallblock1,
.smallblock2,
.smallblock3 {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
.smallblock1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}
.smallblock2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.smallblock3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.Largeblock {
  width: 500px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id ="container">
  <div class="smallblock1"></div>
  <div class="smallblock2"></div>
  <div class="smallblock3"></div>
  <div class="Largeblock"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Full screen your code. The blue div doesn't align to the right like the OP asked for.

Comment: @j08691 I understood it was the right side of the small blocks. Edited to align it to the right.

Comment: Well he said "the fourth (blue box) should be aligned on the right side of the column", so I have to assume that the container div is his column. He didn't say to the right of the other divs.

Comment: OK, I removed my downvote since you got it to work, however that `direction: rtl;` is rather hacky.

Comment: @j08691 Of course it would be preferable to place the big block at the top and float it to the right. But since the elements can't be reordered, I used this trick. Note it's completely standard, not a hack.

Comment: Well I disagree on that being "completely standard" since the direction property is meant for setting  text in different languages like Hebrew and Arabic, and not intended for positioning layout blocks, but there's no need to debate this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible as is, but if you could wrap the 3 smallblock elements in a container, you could position that to the left and the largeblock to the right.  Alternatively, if the number and shape of blocks may vary, it may be worth looking into something like the Masonry plugin (http://masonry.desandro.com/) or Isotope (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) for JQuery to position the elements.  These position the elements in a list such that they form a grid as best as possible, like windows tiles, but they use relative positioning, which may not be what you're after by the sound of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
[class*="smallblock"] {
    float: left;
    clear:left;
}

.Largeblock {
  margin-left: 300px; /* only in this specific instance */
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mgnctjk1/2/)

Note: This only works given these *specific* element sizes and so is not responsive.

---

**`flexbox` solution**

```css
#container {
  width: 800px;
  height:1000px;
  background-color:grey;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
}

[class*="smallblock"] {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 200px;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 200px;
          flex: 0 0 200px;
  width: 200px; 
}

.smallblock1 {
  background-color:black; 
}
.smallblock2 {
  background-color:red;    
}
.smallblock3 {

  background-color:yellow;      
}
.Largeblock {
  width:500px; 
  -webkit-box-flex: 0; 
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 1000px; 
      -ms-flex: 0 0 1000px; 
          flex: 0 0 1000px;
  background-color:blue;
  -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
      -ms-flex-item-align: end;
          align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div id ="container">
    <div class="smallblock1"></div>
    <div class="smallblock2"></div>
    <div class="smallblock3"></div>
    <div class="Largeblock"></div>    
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/eNaWOx)

Same Caveats apply.

Comment: Full screen your code. The blue div doesn't align to the right like the OP asked for.

Comment: Missed that part (fixed)...but all solutions here are pretty hacky I think.

Answer (score -1):

You could solve this by reordering your html like this:

```
<div id ="container">
    <div class="smallblock1"></div>
    <div class="Largeblock"></div>
    <div class="smallblock2"></div>
    <div class="smallblock3"></div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
#container {
   width: 700px;
   height:1000px;
   background-color:grey;
}
.smallblock1 {
   float: left;  
   width: 200px; 
   height:200px;
   background-color:black; 
}
.smallblock2 {
   float: left;  
   width: 200px; 
   height:200px;
   background-color:red;  
}
.smallblock3 {
   float: left;
   width: 200px; 
   height:200px;
   background-color:yellow;      
 }
.Largeblock {
   float: right;
   width:500px; 
   height:1000px;
   background-color:blue;     
}
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7z9vbxg3/10/ or as previous stated wrap them in another container like: https://jsfiddle.net/7z9vbxg3/9/

Comment: OP has stated that the HTML cannot be changed,